# Knowing the number of elements stored in an array in VC++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Is there any way to find the number of elements in an array in VC++ without using for loop.

Let us say array has 16 elements;

```
int a[16];
a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

Now I if I want to get the length to be equal to 7 & NOT 16 (I mean I want to know the number of elements stored in this array instead of getting the number of spaces in the array). Is there any way similiar to the `length()` functions we have in C#?
I am using VC++ on VS2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No built in way. You'ld need to store the number somewhere yourself, or maybe store some end indicator flag.

Comment: Your code is not legal C++ to begin with.  You can initialize the array, i.e. -- `int a[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` -- But you cannot assign it after the fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For built-in arrays, the only way to do this is for you to keep track of this "length" yourself. There's no automatic way of doing it.

A better way, however, is to use `std::vector<int>`. It automatically keeps track of both the current number of elements (the "size") and the number of elements that can be accommodated without re-allocating the array (the "capacity").

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible, If you do not fill the entire array the remaining elements will be filled with values depending on type on initialization.

Note that C/C++ do not do bounds checking on arrays neither do they keep track of number if array elements, the language just provides you a contiguous block of memory you asked for, it is your responsibility of how and whether you use it. As well as the number of elements being stored in the array.

You can save yourself a lot of problems and bookkeeping simply by using an **[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)**.
It provides you with everything an normal array would but with a number of useful member functions like `size()` which do the bookkeeping for you about number of elements etc.